# sorting numbers from a .txt doc into different category with if statements and loops

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

```
public class CreditCardHolder
{
/**
 * This method is used to hold credit card numbers
 */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        File cardNumbers = new File("creditcardnumbers.txt");
        Scanner cardNumbersInput = new Scanner(cardNumbers);


        //cardNumbersInput.useDelimiter("| " + System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        while(cardNumbersInput.hasNext())
        {

            String cardNumber = cardNumbersInput.nextLine();           

            //System.out.println(cardNumber);
            if((cardNumber.length() < 18) || (cardNumber.length() > 15))
            {
               System.out.println(cardNumber + " Is a Mastercard card");
            } 
            else if(cardNumber.length() == 14 )
            {
                System.out.println(cardNumber + " This is a American Express card");
            }
            else if((cardNumber.length() > 12) || (cardNumber.length() < 15))
            {
                System.out.println(cardNumber + " This is a Visa card");
            }
        }

        cardNumbersInput.close();
    }    
}
```

my numbers are:
123456789123454
162626262626262622b
12345678901234

i want them to all be sorted into the places they are supposed to and print what type of card they are depending on the character count, they all keep falling into the first if statement when it is not true. Because all three should be into all different subcategorys

Comment: When will `if((cardNumber.length() < 18) || (cardNumber.length() > 15))` be false? You probably meant `&&`

Comment: oops no wonder why, im sorry. other than that everything is good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the **AND** (&&) operator instead of the **OR** (||) operator within the conditions for your **IF** statements, for example:

```
if((cardNumber.length() > 15) && (cardNumber.length() < 18)) {
    // Do whatever .................
}
```